# Installing a Gmail add-on in domain doesn't work

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-addons

I have a published Gmail add-on. (Not (yet) a GSuite add-on, maybe that's relevant.)

It works, when I install in a Gmail account, or do an "individual installation" in a Gmail account that's part of a Gsuite.

However, when I use the "install in domain" button to install it, my add-on does not appear in Gmail. There's no sign anywhere and no entries in the stackdriver log, nor error messages during the installation.

I have confirmed this for 3 GSuite accounts.

Unconfirmed maybes: On one account, the domain-installation suddenly started working after doing an individual install+uninstall once, but I didn't try that on the other accounts. On another account I got reports that the add-on was extremely slow to respond. (like 1min instead of 1s.)

Does anyone have an idea how to tackle this or if upgrading to a "Gsuite add-on" will make any difference?

Comment: How did you install the add-on? Can you provide more information about this? Are you able to see anything by checking the Admin console and going to [**Apps** > **Marketplace**](https://admin.google.com/AdminHome#AppsList:serviceType=MARKETPLACE)?@leuk98743 – ale13 ?@leuk98743

Comment: Installation: By going to the app's page in the GSuite marketplace and hitting the "install in domain" button; Seeing: I can't easily check (because the failing system isn't mine), but it's very likely because I remember uninstalling the add-on from there for the next round of testing.

Comment: Can you confirm that the add-on is indeed visible in the Admin console? @leuk98743

Comment: The plugin has become visible. Seems like the install takes much longer on some systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin has become visible. Seems like the install takes much longer on some systems. So I'm closing this question.